# Show content from other domain without changing url using .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

Before making it duplicate, just check the question once. Already gone through many of the questions similar to this one but none of them worked for me. I'm messing with this since last few days and I don't know much more about `.htaccess` file in Symfony. I want to show the content from other page when accessed by specific sub domain.

For ex :-
When I accessed this URL - `https://docs.username.example.com/is/share/abcd123`
It should show the content from - `https://example.com/is/share/username/Doc/abcd123`

Another ex :-
When I accessed this URL - `https://username.example.com/is/login`
It should show the content from - `https://example.com/is/login?ref=username`

Notice the username in both examples from querstring to sub-domain.

I've tried several ways but not getting any success
 - RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).(.*).example.com/is/share/(.*)$
 - RewriteRule https://example.com/is/share/username/Doc/abcd123$1 [P]
 - RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).(example.com)$ [NC]
 - RewriteRule ^(index.php)$ http://%2/$1?ref=%1 [L,QSA,NC,R]
 - RewriteRule ^https://username.example.com/is/$ ^https://username.com/$ [L]
 - RewriteRule ^docs.([a-zA-Z0-9]+).example.com/is/share/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) https://example.com/is/share/$1/Doc/$2 [QSA,L]
 - RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).(.*)?example.com$ [NC]
 - RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]

Comment: put an example for HTTP_HOST value? I believe this is a constant something like https://dosc.username  OR https://username

Comment: ***put an example for HTTP_HOST value?*** How? Can you please explain and can't get you about constant. I'm totally unaware of .htaccess content

Comment: your code is using, as shown in your original post, the HTTP_HOST constant value. What is the value you expect it to have?

Comment: If you are talking about domain then example.com would be primary (loads content) and docs.username.domain.com should be show in the URL (user access this URL and show content from primary domain)